# change every letter in a text file and print

Tags: java, io, java-io

I want to change every letters in a text file. But i have this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Soru3.main(Soru3.java:31)

String line;

```
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        line = inputStream.nextLine();
        String[] harfler = line.split("");
        String satir = "";

        char[] ary = new char[harfler.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
            ary[i]=harfler[i].charAt(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

            if ( ( ((int) ary[i] <= 77) && ((int) ary[i] >= 65)) 
                    && (((int) ary[i] >= 97) && ((int)ary[i] <= 109)))

                ary[i] = (char) ( (int)(ary[i]) + 13) ;

            else if ((((int) ary[i] > 77) && ((int) ary[i] <= 90))
                    && (((int) ary[i] > 109) && ((int) ary[i] <= 122)))

                ary[i] = (char) ((int) ary[i] - 11);

            else {
                ary[i]=ary[i];
            }

            System.out.println(satir + line);
        }

    }
    inputStream.close();
```

Comment: harfler[i].charAt(0); here you are getting exception.. better check null !=harfler[i]  or "".euals(harfler[i]) before using this.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen when you have an empoty line in your text file. In order to avoid this, you would need to change you loop from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length() != 0 && ary.length; i++) {
```

When you have an empty line, your line would not have any character in it and we know that String is backed up by character array. So when line is empty, you don't have any element in char array and you are trying to access 0th element using `ary[i]=harfler[i].charAt(0);` in your for loop and hence you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'ary' has harfler.length elements, you should change your main loop from :

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting comes as a result of a empty line in the source file. Rather than fixing the issue directly I see that you seem to be simply breaking the line down into character array in a long-winded and inefficient fashion.

Why not try:

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
    line = inputStream.nextLine();

    char[] ary = line.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){

    // Rest of code...
```

If there is a possibility that line is `null` you should check for that first too.